# Ran into this paraphrasing of the definition of a sequence of probabilities, what does this notation mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

The problem looks like the following:

$$\mathsf{P}\left(  A_n \text{ i.o}\right) \;=\; \mathsf{P}\left(\bigcap_{n \ge1} \bigcup_{m\ge n } A_m\right)$$

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I can't see that the expression on the right depends on n, so it can't be the thing on the left, whatever that is.

Comment: @Paul Actually the thing on the left also does not depend on $n$. It is the probability of event: $$\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\{n\mid\omega\in A_n\}\text{ is infinite }\}$$

Comment: My guess is that the "i.o" emendation is an abbreviation for "infinitely often".  Even so it is unclear what connection this has with probability.  Perhaps as @drhab suggests we should just consider this to be a way of defining a set from a sequence of sets $A_n$.  That one might want to apply a probability measure to that defined set is not clear, and would be worth an edit (if you know).  Otherwise there is little more that can be said, assuming it just to be by *definition*.  One might discuss what one needs to know about the family of sets $A_n$ (you say that they form a sequence).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Borel Cantelli lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma).  "i.o " here stands for "infinitely often."  The result of the infinite intersections of infinite unions of events will be the event consisting of those outcomes who occur infinitely often within the sequence of events.

Looking at the right hand side more closely: suppose $x$ occurs within only finitely many of the events $A_i$.  Then there is some finite highest index where it exists as an element, call that $N$.  Then in the $n+1$'st intersection where we intersect with $\bigcup\limits_{m\geq N+1}A_m$ we will not have $x$ as an element there and therefore $x$ is not an element of the final result.

Suppose otherwise that $x$ occurs infinitely often.  Then for every finite choice of index $n$ there is necessarily going to be some index $N$ larger than $n$ such that $x\in A_N$.  Thus for every finite choice of $n$ will will have the $n$'th intersection will involve the union of events including $A_N$ for whatever that $N$ happened to be and so $x$ will be an element of the union.  Since $x$ is an element of the union for every event in the intersection, it will be an element of the intersection as a whole.

The left hand side is simply the shorthand notation for this.

Comment: Tyvm for this answer. I really appreciate that you took your time to write this :)